# The balances not matching in binance smart chain

Tags: ethereum, binance, go-ethereum, binance-smart-chain

The balances not matching when I subtract and add all the transfer transactions.

https://bscscan.com/token/0x8076c74c5e3f5852037f31ff0093eeb8c8add8d3?a=0xc05E531A586e6525D5c01fBe913babF376F62E2C

If I add all the transfers it will result in
Sent       =  787,262,474.060123392
Received   =  837,747,804.081479654

Balance = 5,04,85,330.02135626

But the current balance which is in blockchain is
0.023373482 SAFEMOON

Why there is discrepancy

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to the tokenomics of the tokens you are buying/selling.

Check the contracts details of safemoon token:

https://bscscan.com/token/0x8076c74c5e3f5852037f31ff0093eeb8c8add8d3#readContract

Here you can see there is a 10% tax on every transfer, including transfer between wallets. This 10% is taken in tokens.

Example:

You buy 100 xyz with 10% tax you only receive 90 xyz and so on.

Your missing tokens went to the token unique fees

Comment: Thank you, So when the fee is paid it does not result in transfer event?